# validar datos al seleccionar una opcion en un combobox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un select con los siguientes datos:

```html
<select name="entidad" id="entidad">
    <option disabled selected>Seleccionar Entidad</option>
    <option>TODAS</option>                                             
    <option>BANCOLOMBIA</option> 
    <option> BANCO BBVA</option> 
    <option>COOTRAPELDAR</option>
    <option> DIEBOLD</option>                                
 </select>
```

y ademas tengo dos input para realizar una consulta por rango de fechas.
lo que quiero es crear una funcion en js que al elegir una opcion del select me valide si los input con el `id="start_date"` de las fechas esten vacios, sino estan vacios me realice la consulta normalmente. Pero aun no se como hacerlo. ¿Alguien me explicaria como podria hacerlo?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Agregar un listener a cada cambio en el `select`
- Dentro de la función de listener recoger el valor del input `start_date`
- Verificar si dicho valor no está vacío mediante `if (startDate)`
- Nótese que se ha usado `trim` al crear la variable `startDate`, para al menos controlar los espacios en blanco no sean considerados como valores reales. Ya que el input recogerá un campo del tipo fecha, convendría sin duda establecer un nivel de validación más estricto, pero este no es el propósito principal de la pregunta...
- Nótese que se ha agregado un valor a cada `option`, el cual se puede recuperar siempre mediante `this` si hiciera falta. Esto es particularmente útil cuando se quieren hacer consultas basadas en esa opción seleccionada. Supongamos que cada número representaría una columna `ID` en una base de datos, en lugar de usar el nombre del banco, es mucho mejor usar el `ID` numérico del mismo.
- A partir de ahí, dentro del primer `if` podrías implementar una llamada a Ajax, que enviará los datos al servidor y te traerá la respuesta.

Aquí te dejo el código:

```js
var selEntidad = document.getElementById("entidad");

selEntidad.addEventListener("change", function(event) {

  var startDate = document.getElementById("start_date").value.trim();
  if (startDate) {
    console.log("no está vacío... proceder. \nAquí tienes el valor del select: " + this.value + "\ny este es el del input: " + startDate);
  } else {
    console.log("está vacío...");
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="start_date" type="date" placeholder="Escriba la fecha" />
<select name="entidad" id="entidad">
    <option disabled selected>Seleccionar Entidad</option>
    <option value="1">TODAS</option>
    <option value="2">BANCOLOMBIA</option> 
    <option value="3"> BANCO BBVA</option> 
    <option value="4">COOTRAPELDAR</option>
    <option value="5"> DIEBOLD</option>                             
 </select>
```

Answer (score 4):

Si lo quieres con javascript puro usa el evento [`onchange()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)  del `select`:

```js
 function validarInputs(){
   if(document.getElementById("start_date").value =="")
     {
        alert("Fecha inicio vacía");
     }
     else
     {
      if(document.getElementById("end_date").value ==""){
       alert("Fecha fin vacía");
        }
        else
        {
          //Todo correcto
        }            
     }    
   }
```

```html
<select name="entidad" id="entidad" onchange="validarInputs()">
    <option disabled selected>Seleccionar Entidad</option>
    <option>TODAS</option>                                             
    <option>BANCOLOMBIA</option> 
    <option> BANCO BBVA</option> 
    <option>COOTRAPELDAR</option>
    <option> DIEBOLD</option>                                
 </select>
 <input type="date" id="start_date"/>
 <input type="date" id="end_date"/>
```

Y si quieres con JQuery puedes utilizar `on.("change",...)` o el método [`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/):

```js
$("#entidad").on("change", function(){
  if($("#start_date").val() =="")
     {
        alert("Fecha inicio vacía");
     }
     else
     {
      if($("#end_date").val() ==""){
         alert("Fecha fin vacía");
      }
        else
        {
           //Todo correcto
        }
        
     }    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="entidad" id="entidad">
    <option disabled selected>Seleccionar Entidad</option>
    <option>TODAS</option>                                             
    <option>BANCOLOMBIA</option> 
    <option> BANCO BBVA</option> 
    <option>COOTRAPELDAR</option>
    <option> DIEBOLD</option>                                
 </select>
 <input type="date" id="start_date"/>
 <input type="date" id="end_date"/>
```

Para el envío, ¿en qué consistiría exactamente? ¿Un envío a servidor? En ese caso te aconsejo que le eches un vistazo a [las llamadas ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Me funciona perfectamente la validacion, pero ahora como hago que despues de la validacion me envie los datos a la Base de Datos. se que con el select se puede agregar un `onchange=submit();` pero en js no se como los podria enviar.

Comment: Lo mejor es que utilices AJAX.

Comment: y no se podria realizar de una manera diferente a ajax, porque en el proyecto no me dejan utilizar ajax por el momento